# Android syncadapter - not displaying Contact sync on certain devices

Tags: android, permissions, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

In a school project, I have implemented a working syncadapter for syncing contacts with my apps. 
I have tried it on an emulator and a HTC Evo 3D on Android 4.0.3 and it works.

But On certain devices (HTC Hero 4.0.3 and Xperia X10 2.3.7) when I add an account for my app, the account does not display the line for syncing contact. I have seen on those devices that in logCat the WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS is not granted.

In the meantime I have seen market app (not system app eg: Hotmail) can have an account with the same contact line I can't have.

How do they do that ? And what can I do about it ?

I just need a quick answer the deadline is very close.

Comment: `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` is/should be `signatureOrSystem` (i.e. only system apps or apps signed with the platform cert. can use it) and you shouldn't be requesting it.

Comment: Is there a way to add an account without password to add contact in the system without that permission ?
Or how can I sign my application for that ?

Comment: Well, for starters it would help to see: The XML definitions you used for your sync adapter, the account authenticator, some snippets from your account authenticator itself - including the place where you call `ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, "com.android.contacts", 1)` to enable contacts sync etc.

Comment: Typically, you'd use the following permissions for a bare-bones adapter + authenticator: `MANAGE_ACCOUNTS`, `AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS`, `WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS` (for calling `setIsSyncable`) - and maybe `GET_ACCOUNTS` & `USE_CREDENTIALS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comment it helped me out.
I just removed the permission and look after the xml line by line to fine a litle mispealing in a XML.
Everything works fine now.
So if you are in my case just try to see for what reason you need each permission and it can solve the problem.

Thanks for the help.